# http error 500 internal server error from another machine

Tags: iis, webserver, iis-6, windows-server-2012-r2

This is probably something very simple. I set up a simple ASP-based web server on Server 2012R2 and IIS6. The IP address of the web server is 192.168.18.142. I then opened up a browser (Chrome). Any of these URLs bring up the website on the web server just fine.

- http://localhost/
- http://127.0.0.1/
- http://192.168.18.142/

  Then I went to a *different* machine (behind the same router), opened the browser and tried to bring up:
- http://192.168.18.142/

However I received this error in the browser:

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

I even tried turning off the Windows Firewall on the web server to no avail. Any idea what configuration settings to look at?

Why does the URL work when on the web server but not from other machine?

Comment: Can the webserver reach the other server(with the resource)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. All the resources are on the web server.

Comment: The error implies that the server cannot load a resource...

Comment: Right, but what resource? It works fine if I use the browser on the web server itself. If I look at the IIS Manager I do not see any settings for resources.

Comment: Are there logs on the server that specify the error?

Comment: Nothing appears in the server's log files in `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1`

Comment: stdout/stderr of the server?

Comment: Sorry, but I am an IIS newbie, so I don't understand what you are referring to.

Comment: stdout and stderr are the standard output/error streams of any program but I don't think your server writes something to them(or it writes the same thing to the log file)

Comment: You have to enable FRT to learn more, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Sounds like the request from another machine didn't land on your IIS machine, but somewhere else.

Comment: It is landing on the IIS machine, because if I specify a page that does not exist, I get a 404 error instead of a 500 error.

Comment: You could try to enable the detailed error message in iis so you will get what exactly causing the issue.
set below code in your web.config file:`<configuration> <system.webServer<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" /><asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/></system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>`
Which permission you assigned to the site folder and under which identity your application pool is running? under which port your application is running? also, try to ping the server.

Comment: is your issue resolved?